# IndentationError: Expected an indented block - Python machine learning cat/dog

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

That's my code:

```
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
prediction = 'dog'
else:
prediction = 'cat' `
```

and I have such error:

```
File "<ipython-input-31-35ebf5fa8bf7>", line 7
prediction = 'dog'
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not properly indented:

```
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
 test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
```

Answer (score 0):

Blocks in python work on indentation. Refer:
"https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation"

```
Your code should be like:  
if result[0][0] == 1:  
<4 spaces>prediction = 'dog'  
else:  
<4 spaces>prediction = 'cat'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, indentation matters.
Thus you need to indent blocks (e.g. the things that go inside an `if`):

```
if result[0][0] == 1:
  prediction = 'dog'
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Python looping constructs like if, for etc require proper indentation following the :.
You should press enter after you type : in your IDE to automatically jump to the position where you should add the next line of code that will be in the loop. If you don't indent it properly python make think its either outside the if loop or throw an indentation error. Your code should be as follows:

```
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg',target_size=(64,64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
```